# WPF debug freezes computer with windows 7 64bit

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, freeze

I am using visual studio 2010 on Windows 7 64bit.

I compiled and ran a simple application basically a thing a child could make.
Well the second it started to run, it froze my computer and rendered it unresponsive.
It continues to do this every time and for every application.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.

COMODO Antivirus/Firewall blocks all applications from calling DLL's, you have to click "Allow" on the dialog that normally pops-up. But since its a DirectX DLL for WPF (since WPF uses DirectX) it froze windows along with my app.