# WPF application completely locking up computer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7

I am (was) experiencing problems with my WPF application completely locking up my computer (it would freeze mouse/keyboard so no CTRL-ALT-DEL, although the hard drive could be seen to be working still) which is the exact same issue discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559274/wpf-c-sharp-application-will-freeze-my-whole-computer-ever-2-3-times-i-run-it), however the solution there is not relevant.

I then found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034657/wpf-debug-freezes-computer-with-windows-7-64bit) which (seems) to have proved the mustard (basically, the issue was that Comodo firewall prevents applications from accessing DLLs willy-nilly without user confirmation and since the WPF app was prevented from accessing DirectX.dll it somehow causes a system freeze before Comodo can even display the confirmation dialog).

I started writing this before I found the second question and my question was basically going to be "WTF?".

Now my question is there some way around this? Does anybody else see this sort of behaviour? I just find it hard to believe that such a small issue could bring a system to it's knees so thoroughly. More importantly I wonder if there is something I can do to prevent such things from happening to me or any of my users in the future, other than preemptively giving my applications permission in the firewall.

I had wondered if there is something unique to my application that was causing problems. I even tried creating a new application with the same UI but absolutely no logic - just a window with a few controls added that did nothing - but encountered the same freezing issue when running it. However, the application didn't freeze my system every time. Maybe it comes down to luck of timing - I was able to see the Comodo confirmation dialog sometimes and could give permission and continue.

If it is just a luck of the timing thing, I would think I would have applications freezing my system left, right and center. Maybe I don't use many apps that are built on WPF, but I use Visual Studio and it is I believe. I don't recall VS shutting down my system like this (except a few times when I tried to debug my own application). I can't swear to it, but it may be that I got lucky and granted full access to Visual Studio the first time I ran it so I never had a chance to experience this issue afterwards...

For you WPF developers, do you run into this sort of issue often in the wild?

Comment: Is it just a window ordering issue? You get some popup behind your application window? Can you pass the appropriate window handle into the dialog?

Comment: Thanks for comment Brannon, from my perspective, my app contains a single window. The pop dialog I mentioned was from my firewall.

Comment: To the downvoter, please have the courtesy to indicate why you downvoted. To my mind, this is a legit question - I faced a situation, found a SO solution that seems to fix and I'm curious if this situation is faced often and if there is some way we can deal with it (other than telling users to shut down their firewall after the app has already crashed). It can't just be two people who have seen this happen...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  We have a WPF app that causes system hangs on random workstations.

Comment: @MikeJansen, sorry no. I never found a useful reason/solution apart from making sure the app has firewall permissions so it wouldn't cause the Comodo permissions dialog to open.